# mySQL 'where name NOT IN' not working?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this statement:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM players
WHERE this = 1 
  AND name NOT IN (SELECT name 
                   FROM players_online 
                   WHERE this = 'that')
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 3, 6
```

All columns are correctly named. No SQL errors occur, it just returns no results.

From what I've read in documentation it should work, but doesn't.

Any idea?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You probably have a `null` value in `players_online.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `NOT IN` with subqueries.  It has the wrong semantics if any value in the subquery is `NULL`.  In that case, the `NOT IN` never evaluates to TRUE, so no rows are returned at all.

Instead, use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name
FROM players p
WHERE p.this = 1 AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM players_online po
                  WHERE po.name = p.name AND po.this = 'that'
                 )
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3, 6;
```